# I'm having problems insert a PHP $_GET variable into my mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, insert

This is a link that uses the $_GET method to pass category to a form

```
echo '<li><font class = "categories_list"><a href="postform.php?ct=' . $value[4] . '"</a>' . $value[0] . '</font></li>';
```

Once in the form I try to retrieve the $_GET variable and it echo's it correctly

```
if(isset($_GET['ct'])) 
{
echo $_GET['ct'];
$catname = $_GET['ct'];
}
```

Once I try to insert into my Mysql table it doesn't insert..

```
"INSERT INTO almt1(idnum, catname)
    VALUES ('$idnum', '$catname')";
```

When I do insert it goes in as an empty value

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Show us the code where you insert it.  Do you get an error from mysql when you try to insert?

Comment: Your insert code is fine, echo the result right before the insert.

Comment: you probably want to do something to sanatize your inputs prior to building your query though.

Answer (score 0):

write your query like this

```
"INSERT INTO almt1(idnum, catname)
VALUES ($idnum, $catname)";
```

or,

```
"INSERT INTO almt1(idnum, catname)
VALUES ('".$idnum."', '".$catname."')";
```

Comment: How about at least suggesting the OP uses [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇƇhƐȓ0nè must be used from preventing sqlInjection.

Comment: I'm using mysqli and I don't get any errors just inserts as null

Comment: @AnthonyLiriano Well you need to use [mysqli prepared querys](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: When I do insert it goes in as an empty value using
    "INSERT INTO almt1(idnum, catname)
VALUES ('".$idnum."', '".$catname."')";

Comment: @AnthonyLiriano echo the query before executing it and tell us $idnum and $catname is containning its value...

Comment: The $idnum is the only containing its value

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget about security.
If you are using MySQL, use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on GET parameters.

For example:

```
$catname = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['catname']);
```

Comment: `$catname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection_link, $_GET['catname']);`

Comment: I used your suggestions it still doesn't insert the variable to the table but keep it there for security reasons